# Using Python library on an iOS Swift project

Tags: python, ios, swift, py2app

There is this Python library that I want to use with my iOS app, so I have been exploring how to do that.
I have gone pretty far, creating a bundle with my Python installation using the py2app (somewhat based on this post: https://github.com/ndevenish/Site-ndevenish/blob/master/_posts/2017-04-11-using-python-with-swift-3.markdown, without the symlinks).
So I have the `main.swift` file loading my bundle, but when the app loads instead of viewing the message on the main file, I am getting an error.

> Error loading
>   /Users/blablabla/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C465435B-4EF3-4CDC-98E7-9ACF11C6736C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29C18165-D120-447E-A912-F4B4AFC77966/MyPython.app/Bridge.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Bridge:
>   dlopen(/Users/blablabla/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C465435B-4EF3-4CDC-98E7-9ACF11C6736C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29C18165-D120-447E-A912-F4B4AFC77966/MyRDP.app/Bridge.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Bridge, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /Users/blablabla/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C465435B-4EF3-4CDC-98E7-9ACF11C6736C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/29C18165-D120-447E-A912-F4B4AFC77966/MyPython.app/Bridge.plugin/Contents/MacOS/Bridge:
>   mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

Any idea on what I should do to make it work? Below I will post some files of what I have:

main.swift

```
import UIKit

let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Bridge", ofType: "plugin")
guard let pluginbundle = Bundle(path: path!) else {
    fatalError("Could not load python plugin bundle")
}
pluginbundle.load()

let ret = UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc,
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer(CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
        .bindMemory(
            to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.self,
            capacity: Int(CommandLine.argc)),
    nil,
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
exit(ret)
```

Bridge.py (located on my project root folder)

```
 """Bridge.py. The main Python-(Swift) plugin bundle entry module"""
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

logger.info("Loaded python bundle")
```

And finally, my setup.py from py2app

```
"""Setuptools setup for creating a .plugin bundle"""
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['Bridge.py']
OPTIONS = {
  # Any local packages to include in the bundle should go here.
  # See the py2app documentation for more
  "includes": ['mylib'], 
}

setup(
    plugin=APP,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
    install_requires=['pyobjc'],
)
```

Comment: Hello! [Hope you are doing these steps](https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html)

Comment: Hi @Rex, which step exactly are you referring too?

Comment: As per the error, Path is not accessing. [These are the steps to import the python](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html)

Comment: @Rex if I try without my library, I got the same error. I don't think it is related with the path of my library (if that's what you are talking about)